# What is the difference between choosing 2 teams while assigning them colours and simply choosing the teams?

Tags: combinatorics

I am asking in general, but I will include some specific numbers to make this easier.

There is a class of 30 students. The PE teacher wants to select 3 teams of 4 students each to compete in a school sports tournament.

My questions are "how many combinations are possible under these circumstances?" and "what difference would it make if, besides selecting the students, he also assigned each team a colour?" (for example, he will assign the colours red, yellow and blue).

I know these are different, I just want to know, in practice what I must and mustn't do when facing each situation.

Comment: Team A as red and Team B as blue is different from Team A as blue and Team B as red.  Without coloring there is no difference.

Comment: What are your thoughts on it? Can you please add to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be the answer:

(1) When the teams have no colours

The teacher can first choose the 12 students that will participate. Then he/she will choose 4 students out of those 12 for the first team, and then 4 students out of the remaining 8. Since the order in which the teacher chooses the teams should not matter we divide by $3!$. Thus the total number should be
$${30\choose 12}\left\{ {12\choose 4}{8\choose 4}\frac{1}{3!}\right\}.$$

(2) If the teams have different colours then we can assume w.l.o.g. that the first team will be assigned blue, the second red and the third yellow, so we simply remove the $1/3!$ factor.

This should be easy to generalise. Namely, first make a choice of the students that will participate, and then count the number of teams that you can make (after the first selection you can evenly divide the number of students by the size of the teams).